# The project targets '.NET Framework 4.5' which is not supported on the Windows Azure virtual machine (OSFamily = '4')

Tags: azure

I have a asp.net project that is published to azure as a cloud service.

The asp.net project targets the .net 4.5 framework. Its currently deployed to azure and works.

However when I publish it to azure form Visual Studio, I get the following warning@

warning WAT250: The project targets '.NET Framework 4.5' which is not supported on the Windows Azure virtual machine (OSFamily = '4').  To make sure that the role starts, update the 'osFamily' attribute in the service configuration file 'ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg'.  See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=262840 from more information.

My project targets osFamily="4", which is Windows Server 2012 R2, and according to the link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=262840, Windows Server 2012 R2 supports the .net 4.5 framework, so why do I get a warning?

My file contains the following osFamily="4" osVersion="*" and also my role does start without any problems.....

Can anyone advise on why I get this warning?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to update your Azure SDK?